# When Statments with LIKE and Substrings

Tags: mysql, substring, sql-like, case-when

I am in school and trying to figure out this question asked by the instructor. I have not asked the instructor because he usually gets back to me 2 weeks down the road.

Here is what the questions is asking:

Using the weblog table in your database create a query that will use the WHEN statement to:

categorize the records by the origcmd field meeting the following conditions
Your categories should be as follows:

•Category 1 = origcmd starts with GET

•Category 2 = origcmd starts with POST

•Category 3 = origcmd starts with HEAD

•Category 4 = All of the left over records

•Count the records in each group
•Average the hours part of the origdate field without modifying the field.

I have tried the following without the Average because I cannot get it to pull correctly with the following:

```
Select CASE 
WHEN origcmd LIKE "GET%" THEN "Category 1"
WHEN origcmd LIKE"POST%" THEN "Category 2"
WHEN origcmd LIKE "HEAD%" THEN "Category 3"
Else "Category 4 All of left over records" END as "Original CMD",
Count(*) AS Total
FROM WebLog
```

When using this it only pulls the first WHEN line and ignores all the rest except the count. I am new at this and am having a difficult time trying to understand MySQL. I think I might need to use a SubString cmd but was hoping for a little direction here that might help.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

```
SELECT category,
       CASE category WHEN 1 THEN 'GET' WHEN 2 THEN 'POST' WHEN 3 THEN 'HEAD' ELSE 'OTHER' END command,
       COUNT(*) rec_count, 
       ROUND(AVG(SUBSTRING(origdate, 14, 2))) avg_hour
FROM
(SELECT w.*, 
        CASE WHEN LEFT(origcmd, 3) = 'GET'  THEN 1
             WHEN LEFT(origcmd, 4) = 'POST' THEN 2
             WHEN LEFT(origcmd, 4) = 'HEAD' THEN 3
        ELSE 4 END category
   FROM WebLog w) q
 GROUP BY category
```

Output:

```
| CATEGORY | COMMAND | REC_COUNT | AVG_HOUR |
---------------------------------------------
|        1 |     GET |         4 |       10 |
|        2 |    POST |         3 |       14 |
|        3 |    HEAD |         1 |       17 |
|        4 |   OTHER |         2 |        6 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23f4e/6)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this may help.  The fields are as follows: IPNO, DUNNO, DUNNO2, origdate, origzone, origcmd, recode, and bytes. the records are as follows: 96.247.122.214, -, -, [15/Mar/2008:16:36:09, -0700], GET /templates/247_blue_452/images/modul.jpg HTTP/1.1, 200, 335.  That is just one record and hopefully this helps.  I think my teacher is looking for these fields: Categories, origcmd, Total count, origdate averaged.  With these records: Category 1, GET, 300, 17.000.  Something close to that.  I hope this gives a clearer picture. Thanks for your answer. Regards

Comment: sorry the first comment was by accident still first time asking for help on this and still trying to get used to how to use it. Please see my second comment.  Sorry I am unable to format it so it looks better. regards,

Comment: @user2380034 You should have posted sample data and desired output in your original question (using edit link) in the first place. But anyway see updated answer.

Comment: I will remember next time to include the fields in the original comment.  Thanks for your responses it is greatly appreciated. When running the query it states that there is an unknown column 'category' in the field list. I am not sure but I think that origcmd needs to be in the Select portion however it comes up with other errors when I do that as well.

Comment: @user2380034 Are you sure you use exactly the same query? Did you look at sqlfiddle that I posted in the answer?

Comment: My mistake you are correct it does run exactly how you put it. I must have missed something. I will adjust some of the column names and check it out and let you know but I think this will answer my question. Will let you know soon.  Thanks again